# Span inside List item looks weird in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have problems with positioning span text inside `<li>` element.
It looks good in Mozilla and Chrome but looks awful in IE.

Can some one please help me out.

Here is the style code:

```
ul#barcodesList > li
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-left: 1px solid #2557AD;
    border-right: 1px solid #2557AD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2557AD;
    color: #2557AD;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e7f0fe;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-top: 6px;
 }

 ul#barcodesList > li > span
 {
    float: right;
    color: #FF6A6A;
    display:block;
 }

 ul#barcodesList > li > span:hover
 {
     display:block;
     color: red;
 }
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul id="barcodesList">
<li>00015<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
<li>RA075605345SI<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
<li>110002067 20130200<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
<li>PP2013001200<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
<li>PP2013001201<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
<li>PP2013001202<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is how its buit (jQuery):

```
        $(function () {
            $.each(barcodes, function(key, value) {
                $("#barcodesList").append("<li>" + key + "</li>");
            });

            deleteButton = $('<span />').addClass('deleteButton').text('Delete');
            $('ul#barcodesList li').append(deleteButton);
...
```

And the effect (right is IE, left is Chrome)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ul#barcodesList > li > span remove display block

Comment: else give fixed width or `max-width`.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing? And can you confirm that it's not in compatibility mode or quirks mode?

Comment: thanks, but that didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
<li>RA075605345SI<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span></li>
```

to

```
<li><span class="deleteButton">Delete</span> RA075605345SI</li>
```

so:

```
    $('ul#barcodesList li').prepend(deleteButton);
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but would you help me re-structure jQuery portion?

Comment: too obvious to realize ... thans a lot Wes

Answer (score 1):

I Have something similar, which works fine for me. her is my code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

.divfab {
float:right;
align:right;}
</style> 


<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=en" >Leftsided Text 1 <div class="divfab" align="right">Error 1</div></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=en" >Leftsided Text 2 <div class="divfab" align="right">Error 2</div></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=en" >Leftsided Text 3 <div class="divfab" align="right">Error 3</div></a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=en" >Leftsided Text 4 <div class="divfab" align="right">Error 4</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Testet on IE8, FF20, Chrome Opera 12

Maybee this helps

Comment: Thanks for the effort stake master!